# How to make a jailbroken iPhone appear un-jailbroken to network provider?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, ios

I'd like to jailbreak my iPhone but have it appear to my network provider as if it isn't jailbroken. This should be do-able, but what do I need to do to make this happen?

I have an iPhone 4 currently running iOS 4.2.

EDIT:  Canadian politics is tricky.  Part of the potential new copyright law would make defeating any sort of weak sauce encryption illegal. Essentially, the copyright holder would have it's rights fully supported, and as for the user, well they get what's left. This is going on at the same time as our bandwidth cap issues. I just want to be proactive, for when the "unforseen QoS problems" begin to arise here. So, not a neutral ISP situation.

Comment: What makes you believe the network provider can see if an iPhone is jailbroken (and nothing else) over the network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only visible change that jailbreaking does is the installation of the cydia app on your homescreen.
what i would suggest is to go into cydia and get an app called **Poof** to hide the cydia icon. You can follow the guide here http://www.iphoneappsandhacks.com/how-to-hide-icons-on-iphone-or-ipod-touch.html, or you can hide it in a folder with a bunch of other apps.

Comment: Is the issue that it appears Jailbroken, when viewed in person, or over the network.  I assume the question is about the over network view.

Comment: Yes, over the network.

Comment: Im not sure they can ever tell over the network.

Answer (score 4):

The network provider can't see if it's jailbroken or not. They might be able to detect if you're using Skype over 3G or other non-3G apps but they won't be able to discover it by simply jailbraking it.

Comment: +1. And if they can see you got a jailbroken iphone, what can they do about it? jailbreaking is legal after all.

Comment: @Cawas Even if it is legal (and I'm not sure it is in all countries), it still might a breach of the terms of service of your carrier.

Comment: @Andris strictly speaking, it'd only be contract breach if the contract specifically said something about "jailbreaking". Otherwise, you're most probably talking about carrier unlock. I've had iPhone for over 2 years always broke it jail free and I have never unlocked the carrier. In fact, historically jailbreaking is not even the only way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

If that's true why can some apps detect it anyway? I installed e.g. Voddler on my iPhone yesterday; a free app to see movies without a charge. I can't see any movies because the app detected my iPhone as jailbroken and I got a message saying that jailbroken devices are not allowed to play the movies.

Comment: There are ways for an application to check if an iPhone is jailbroken. Apple did this same thing with iBooks. They can also check if that copy of the app is pirated. With iBooks, the app would try to run a little bit of code that shouldn't run on iPhones every time it launched. If it ran, the phone was jailbroken, if not, the app loaded as normal.

Comment: And the network provider would have the access too. Damn.